# Difference between ProTeXt-3.1.3-060313.exe and protext.exe?

Tags: packages

I want to download the necessary software to use LATEX.

There are three files presented at http://get-software.net/systems/windows/protext/

Two of the files, which are each about 1.6 GB, are named ProTeXt-3.1.3-060313.exe and protext.exe. Does it matter which one I choose? What is the difference?

Also, what is the purpose of the third file, named ProTeXt-3.1.3-060313.exe.md5, which is only 59 bytes?

Comment: If you are going with ProTeXt, I'd grab stuff straight from CTAN: http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/windows/protext/

Answer (score 1):

The file `protext.exe` is identical to `ProTeXt-<numbers>.exe`, but is there as each different release of ProTeXt will have a different version number. Thus a link to just '`protext.exe`' will alway be correct, but the version number will alter. (At the server, both links point to the same file using what is called a symlink).

The `.md5` file is to allow a security check  (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). These are a little more tricky on Windows than on Unix, but depending on how 'security concious' you are allow you to check that the file you get is unchanged from the 'official' release.